# How to change value by user (inputing field) of global variable inside of function

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Is it possible by `prompt` or somehow that user's can change the value of variable inside this function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<button onclick="myFunction()" style="font-size: 17pt; margin-top: 5%;">Roll it</button>
</center>
<br>
<center>
<span id="demo" style="margin: 10% 5%; font-size: 45pt; color: blue;"></span>
<span id="demo1" style="margin: 2% 5%; font-size: 45pt; color: red;"></span>
</center>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = y;
    if (x == y) {
        myFunction();
        }
    else {
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Should I use `prompt` or `input` field's, and how to affect the changes inside function value.
How to change the value of this variable, from `3` e.g to `5`but without loosing the function effect?

```
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an input, and read it's value in your function. I also improved your function a little (while not changing functionality).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
    <input type="number" id="max" value="3"/>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" style="font-size: 17pt; margin-top: 5%;">Roll it</button>
</center>
<br>
<center>
<span id="demo" style="margin: 10% 5%; font-size: 45pt; color: blue;"></span>
<span id="demo1" style="margin: 2% 5%; font-size: 45pt; color: red;"></span>
</center>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var max = document.getElementById('max').value || 3;
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    do {
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
    } while (x === y);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = y;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jscissr/k8ehjyw5/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
    <input type="text" id="var" />
    <br>
<button onclick="myFunction()" style="font-size: 17pt; margin-top: 5%;">Roll it</button>
</center>
<br>
<center>
<span id="demo" style="margin: 10% 5%; font-size: 45pt; color: blue;"></span>
<span id="demo1" style="margin: 2% 5%; font-size: 45pt; color: red;"></span>
</center>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        debugger
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * document.getElementById("var").value) + 1);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * document.getElementById("var").value) + 1);
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = y;
        if (x == y) {
            myFunction();
        }
        else {
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope help you